# Cacading Dropdown

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I create cascading drop down using custom field type in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow the URL to create custom field type you want [cascading drop down](http://jaypoint.com/sharepoint-cascading-lookup-field-jquery/)